# Small display with no assembling

Tags: gpio, usb, display, screen, terminal

I'd like to buy a display for my pi (B+, I will by it as fast I can). But I can't find any options that does not require assembling. Display can be "anything", like character lcd (http://www.adafruit.com/product/399), small (touch)screen (http://www.adafruit.com/products/1601) or led matrix (https://learn.adafruit.com/connecting-a-16x32-rgb-led-matrix-panel-to-a-raspberry-pi/overview).

It can be connected via hdmi, gpio or usb, but it have to be possible to control it via command line.

And power supply **must be** micro usb or pi itself. It's nice if it's cost under 50€ (70$).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to do it to be honest. There is a solution using the composite port (see http://www.wisegai.com/2012/11/29/raspberry-pi-using-a-3-5-tft-car-monitor-optional-powered-using-usb/) for an example but that requires soldering as well. You might be better off looking at http://hdmipi.com/ - price is just above what you want but it's going to be a good screen. It's not available yet but will be within the next few weeks.

Comment: I also don't think that there exists anything that meets the specs yet, anything small will require adapters/soldering/etc. to get working, and anything large will be outside the price range - I also found [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0V108S5365&cm_re=portable_monitor_1302-_-9SIA0V108S5365-_-Product), which is available now, but still above the budget